# Freenas > Docker > Openproject Container Autostart

Tags: docker, autostart, openproject

I have a virtual Machine for Docker on my freenas system. On this rancheros docker machine I installed the openproject docker container.

With the freenas boot, there will automatically start the docker machine in which I installed the openproject docker container.
But how can I start the openproject container inside automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have configured Docker to start automatically when your VM boots, you can tell Docker to start containers automatically by setting an `always` [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart) on them:

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped ...
```

You can also set a restart policy on an existing container:

```
docker update --restart=unless-stopped mycontainer
```

With a restart policy of `unless-stopped`, Docker will "restart the container regardless of the exit status, including on daemon startup, except if the container was put into a stopped state before the Docker daemon was stopped".

Comment: it works, BUT when I do the "--restart=unless-stopped" option, on every restart I got a clean openproject container without the changed data

Comment: That seems odd, but perhaps you can solve that by mounting a data volume into the container at an appropriate location. I'm not familiar with the openproject image so I can't provide any more direction than that.